# Given an object array, how does one echo the contents?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an object array `$this->result`

When I echo `$this->result` I get `Array`.

When I `print_r($this->result)` I get a blank screen.

How do I find what is being stored in this object array?

EDIT: By blank screen I mean the nothing is being rendered at all.

EDIT2:
Here is the code that renders, but I don't know what it's doing.

```
<?php  
    foreach ($this->result as $r){
        extract($r);
        // Then there is a bunch of code beneath here 
        // that displays different results
   } 
?>
```

However if I do this, the page no longer renders at all.

```
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($this->result, true) . '</pre>';

    foreach ($this->result as $r){
        extract($r);
        // Then there is a bunch of code beneath here 
        // that displays different results
   }
```

EDIT3:

After installing and turning on xdebug, `var_dump` now displays the data. (however `print_r()` still does not). Any thoughts as to why that might be?

Comment: @Jemaclus: Nope, still kicks out a blank screen.

Comment: show us the code you're using. Are you forgetting a `;`?

Comment: Turn on error reporting at the top of your script. `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @webbiedave: error reporing is turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If available, honestly I would use a php debugger like xdebug and set up a debugging client and just inspect it. What is the reason for not knowing the contents of the objects in the array?

print_r when set to true will return the output instead of printing it to the screen.

what about

```
foreach ($this->result as $r){
   print_r($r);
}
```

Comment: xdebug did allow var_dump to now display, but why would it not display on its own?

Comment: xdebug adds in better stack trace information for php. looking back, var_dump seems appropriate for objects. can you post the output of var_dump, maybe this has something to do with the objects in the array?

Comment: was just coding something else, and you should also look into the reflection api.http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Answer (score 4):

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($this->result, true) . '</pre>';
```

[More reading material](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) — See the "return" argument.

Comment: Interesting idea, but still no go. As soon as I try to echo or print or return that result the screen does not render. (No code at all when viewing source in a browser).